# Is the SQL SERVER TOP N clause taking into consideration where filters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I select the first row from a view using the TOP clause, it seems like the conditions inside of the where clause are not respected.

[image: SELECT STATEMENT]

Is using the top clause when filters are present correct?

Comment: Yes.   The `TOP` is executed basically after the result set is generated -- all joins, filters, aggregations and sorts.  If you get no rows, then the where` clause filters out all rows.

Comment: Why do you say it isn't? There are no rows returned, which implies very much that the `WHERE` *is* being respected; otherwise you'd get 1 arbitrary row.

Comment: I don`t get why the reporting_date column is null if I have the following filter "where A.REPORTING_DATE='2020-07-31"

Comment: *"I don't get why the reporting_date column is null"* It isn't, there are **no** rows. `NULL` != *no data*. If the value were `NULL` you  would see a single row, labelled "1" and the value *`NULL`* (with the background colour your tooltip colour) in that row.

Comment: If you're worried about `TOP 1` then remove `TOP 1` and tell us what you get. It should be the same result: no rows. Either your `WHERE` clause is filtering out all rows, or your table has no rows..

Comment: BTW, [There is no "first" row.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/) Database tables are unsorted by nature, if you're using `TOP x` without using `ORDER BY` you're basically telling the database `give me (up to a maximum of) x **arbitrary** rows.

Comment: Yeah, I had no rows, I`m a big dummy. Thanks for the answers I understood how the TOP clause works better now